# Using Aspose Slide to draw graphs

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspose

I am new at using `aspose.slides` and wondering if it would be possible for me to create a bar chart given in this shot description.

The chart that I am trying to update has the y axis from -100 to 100 and the x axis on the 0  and the bar graph should be on the positive side going up or the negative going down.

The code below show for a regular bar chart is bellow

```
// Instantiate PresentationEx class that represents PPTX file
PresentationEx pres = new PresentationEx("D:\\AsposeChart.pptx");

// Access first slide
SlideEx sld = pres.Slides[0];

// Add chart with default data
ChartEx chart = (ChartEx)sld.Shapes[0];

// Setting the index of chart data sheet 
int defaultWorksheetIndex = 0;

// Getting the chart data worksheet
ChartDataCellFactory fact = chart.ChartData.ChartDataCellFactory;

// Take first chart series
ChartSeriesEx series = chart.ChartData.Series[0];

// Now updating series data
fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 1, "New_Series1");//modifying series name
series.Values[0].Value = 90;
series.Values[1].Value = 123;
series.Values[2].Value =44;

// Take Second chart series
series = chart.ChartData.Series[1];

// Now updating series data
fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 2, "New_Series2");//modifying series name           
series.Values[0].Value = 23;
series.Values[1].Value = 67;
series.Values[2].Value = 99;

// Now, Adding a new series
chart.ChartData.Series.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 3, "Series 3"), chart.Type);

// Take 3rd chart series
series = chart.ChartData.Series[2];

// Now populating series data
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 3, 20));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 3, 50));
series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 3, 30));

chart.Type = ChartTypeEx.ClusteredCylinder;

// Save presentation with chart
pres.Write(@"D:\AsposeChartMoodified.pptx");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have observed your requirements and like to share that you may use the following code snippet to serve the purpose of generating desired chart. I have shared the sample code that can render the series in negative region. However, there is small issue that when negative or values less then horizontal scale values are rendered, their fill color is removed.

This is due to missing property in Aspose.Slides and I have created an issue with ID **SLIDESNET-33821** (*you can track the status of this issue in Aspose.Slides product support forum over [this link](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/428573/updateing-a-negaive-bar-chart.aspx)*) to provide the feature support. I have also shared the image that highlights the missing feature and un-checking the encircled values will fill the unfilled series values. In my opinion, if you are using template chart then this issue may not even occur. But you can verify this on your end.

```
public static void addBarChart()
{
    PresentationEx pres = new PresentationEx();
    ChartEx chart = pres.Slides[0].Shapes.AddChart(ChartTypeEx.ClusteredColumn, 20, 20, 500, 400);
    //Setting values of Y-axis or Value axis
    chart.ValueAxis.IsAutomaticMaxValue = false;
    chart.ValueAxis.IsAutomaticMinValue = false;
    chart.ValueAxis.CrossType = CrossesTypeEx.Custom;
    chart.ValueAxis.MinValue = 0;
    chart.ValueAxis.MaxValue = 400;
    chart.ValueAxis.CrossAt = 100f;

    chart.ChartData.Series.Clear();
    int defaultWorksheetIndex = 0;
    //Getting the chart data worksheet
    ChartDataCellFactory fact = chart.ChartData.ChartDataCellFactory;

    //Adding new series
    int id=chart.ChartData.Series.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 1, "Series 1"), chart.Type);
    ChartSeriesEx series = chart.ChartData.Series[id];


    //Now populating series data

    series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 1, 30));
    series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 1, 150));
    series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 3, 1, 320));
    series.Values.Add(fact.GetCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 4, 1, 80));

    series.Format.Fill.FillType = FillTypeEx.Solid;
    series.Format.Fill.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Red;
    series.IsColorVaried = false;
    pres.Write("D:\\Aspose Data\\SampleChart.pptx");

}
```

*PS, My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.*